# Update doesn't work sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Having problem updating a column in a table.  I tried both of these solutions:

```
        this.openDataBase();
        String SQLStatement = "update " + TABLE_POSES;
        SQLStatement += " set " + COLUMN_SKIP + "=" + SKIP + " Where ";
        SQLStatement += COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(skipPoseId);
        myDataBase.rawQuery(SQLStatement, null);
        this.close();
```

and this:

```
        this.openDataBase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COLUMN_SKIP,SKIP);
        myDataBase.update(TABLE_POSES, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" +  String.valueOf(skipPoseId),null);
        this.close();
```

Neither of these code snippets work and I am not getting any exceptions thrown.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting errors? Can you post your LogCat?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions thrown at all.

Comment: I also tried using beginTransaction();and setTransactionSuccessful() statements and this didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second method using `update()` and you should check the return value. If the value is zero, then the state of the database isn't what you expect and no rows were updated. If the row is not zero then the updating is succeeding.

If anything is wrong with your accessing the database an exception will be thrown before the `update()` call.

I would take advantage of the args parameter of `update()` like so:

```
myDataBase.update(TABLE_POSES, args, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ Long.toString(skipPoseId) });
```

Comment: How are you checking if the row is being updated? Unless there is a bug in Android code getting a 1 means that one row was updated.

Comment: I can tell based on the behavior of the app that the column is not being updated.

Comment: @ Kristy You should check your db by extracting the db in SQLite Manager,that the row is updated or not.If yes there could be a chance of a bug in your code.

Comment: I hate to suggest it but there must be something else that's not happening correctly. Your update is working. If you run it on an emulator, you can retrieve the SQLite database file using Eclipse's DDMS plugin. The database is in /data/data/<app package name>/databases/<database name>. You can open it in any SQLite client and you'll see that the update is working. Inspecting the file is the best way to show that you're doing things right

Comment: Glad to hear it! There still may be a bug in the code that will show itself again when the database is in a specific state

Answer (score 0):

Use update like this,

```
        String query="UPDATE tablename SET columnname="+var+ "where columnid="+var2;
        sqlitedb.execSQL(query);
```

Just write your update query in String query and execute.

Comment: It's safer to use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

if you use `db.begintransaction()` in your code you must call `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` before `db.endtransaction()` such as:

```
try {
        SQLHelper dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();
        ...................

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        db.endTransaction();

        db.close();

} 
catch (Exception ex){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue. After much thought and debugging I saw that the WHERE condition wasn't addressing any rows of the table.

The odd thing is that the myDatabase.update command giving 1 as the return and I was understanding it as 1 row affected by the update.